# resize image without losing quality - java

Tags: java

How to resize image without losing its quality using java code ?
I have tried below code.

```
    BufferedImage thumbnail =
              Scalr.resize(inputImage,150, 100);
    String formatName = outputImagePath.substring(outputImagePath
            .lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    ImageIO.write(thumbnail, formatName, new File(outputImagePath));
```

Comment: Depending on the scaling api, you could use a stepped approach, scaling down the image by 50% until you reach your target size

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to resize an image without either throwing pixels away (when making it smaller) or interpolating/duplicating pixels (when making it larger).  Thus, it is impossible to "resize" an image without sacrificing quality.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code, Short and works fine.

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```